# Download container on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cloudberry

Is there a way of downloading a container and all of its content from Azure Blob Storage?

I use CloudBerry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage to manage my containers, files and folders.

I have a container with over 100GB of data which I would like to download, but cannot find a way of downloading the container, only individualy files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want, you can use the `AzCopy` tool to download an entire blob container. Assuming you have the latest version of the Azure SDK installed, you can find this tool in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy` folder.

You can try the following command:

```
AzCopy /Source:"https://[accountname].blob.core.windows.net/[containername]/" /Dest:"[folder path e.g. D:\temp\" /SourceKey:"[account key]" /S
```

Replace [accountname], [containername], [folder path], [account key] with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 16):

**To download the Container (All Files) from Azure Blob Storage**

```
az login

az account set --subscription <Sub ID>

az storage blob download-batch --account-name <storageaccountname> --source <containername> --destination <C:\Users\Downloads\***>
```

**To Delete All files at a time**

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name <storageaccountname> --source <containername>
```

FYI:
You need to run these commands in azure-cli. [Download Azure CLI tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: And where, pray tell, would you run these commands?  Please improve your answer.  I have no idea where to run this from.

Comment: FYI: You need to run these commands in azure-cli. [Download Azure CLI tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli)

Answer (score 0):

az storage blob download-batch --account-name  --source  --destination <C:\Users\Downloads***>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Now Azure Storage Explorer has an option to download all.